# Select column and values where values are greater than 0 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

```
Name: `table1`
name    d1      d2      d3      d4      d5
Tapan   2       0       3       8       0
```

```
another table : `table2`
name    c1      c2      c3      c4      c5      c6
Tapan   12      14      0       0       17      0
```

In both tables there are 50+ columns.
How to get a report like:

```
name    - Tapan
d1      - 2
d3      - 3
d4      - 8
c1      - 12
c2      - 14
c5      - 17
total   - 56
```

I failed to create the sql query for the report where value>0 and name = 'Tapan'

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b 
ON a.name = b.name
```

[See the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418248/5)

I need to get the report  where column value is greater than `0`

Comment: Hint: use union all.

Comment: If you have tables with 50+ columns like this, it would be better to redesign it so that the columns are separate rows.

Comment: Dynamic information should always be in column values, not table or column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF these are the fixed columns and you need that report for name = Tapan only then you can get the desired results using `union all`

```
select a.name , a.tapan
from(
  select 'd1' as name, d1 as tapan from table1 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'd2' as name, d2 as tapan from table1 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'd3' as name, d3 as tapan from table1 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'd4' as name, d4 as tapan from table1 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'd5' as name, d5 as tapan from table1 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'c1' as name, c1 as tapan from table2 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'c2' as name, c2 as tapan from table2 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'c3' as name, c3 as tapan from table2 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'c4' as name, c4 as tapan from table2 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'c5' as name, c5 as tapan from table2 where name = 'Tapan'
  union all
  select 'c6' as name, c6 as tapan from table2 where name = 'Tapan'
) a
where a.tapan > 0
union all
select 'total', sum(a.d1 +a.d2 +a.d3 +a.d4 +a.d5 + b.c1 + b.c2 + b.c3 + b.c4 + b.c5 + b.c6 )
from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.name = b.name where a.name = 'Tapan'
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418248/28)

> Edit for restructure

Create 2 tables one for your data and one for data types like c1 , c2 , d1 and so on like

data_types

```
    id  title   
------  --------
     1  d1      
     2  d2      
     3  d3      
     4  d4      
     5  d5      
     6  c1      
     7  c2      
     8  c3      
     9  c4      
    10  c5      
    11  c6
```

data table

```
    id  name    type_id  type_value  
------  ------  -------  ------------
     1  Tapan         1             2
     2  Tapan         2             0
     3  Tapan         3             3
     4  Tapan         4             8
     5  Tapan         5             0
     6  Tapan         6            12
     7  Tapan         7            14
     8  Tapan         8             0
     9  Tapan         9             0
    10  Tapan        10            17
    11  Tapan        11             0
```

data table will hold the reference of types table as type_id and type_value will store your number related to each name and type and then you can query your required data by using simple join operation

```
SELECT b.`title`,a.`type_value` AS Tapan
FROM `data` a
JOIN `data_types` b ON a.`type_id` = b.`id`
WHERE a.`name` = 'Tapan'
AND a.`type_value` > 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c48da5/1)

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable answer. Actually there are 100+ columns, Then the query will be too long. Will there be any problem for long query?

Comment: @dipakdutta 100+ columns ? Yes there can be a problem and will increase in future as well, i guess you need to think about redesigning your structure.

That is why in start of answer i have mentioned *IF these are the fixed no. of columns*

Comment: It means, Will I change the reporting  structure like name  | d1 | d3 | d4 | c1 | c2 | c5? Then how to report this? Plz...

Comment: let me know if you want me to suggest the table structure i can update my post

Comment: Plz suggest me the table structure

Comment: @dipakdutta i have added new structure for your tables  in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I will implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you redesigned your tables to be like this:

`table1`:

```
Name    Dnum    Dval
Tapan   1       2
Tapan   2       0
Tapan   3       3
Tapan   4       8
Tapan   5       0
```

`table2`:

```
Name    Cnum    Cval
Tapan   1       12
Tapan   2       14
Tapan   3       0
Tapan   4       0
Tapan   5       17
Tapan   6       0
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('d', Dnum) AS name, Dval AS Tapan
FROM table1
WHERE Name = 'Tapan' AND Dval > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('c', Cnum) AS name, Cval AS Tapan
FROM table2
WHERE Name = 'Tapan' AND Cval > 0
```

You could also combine both tables like:

```
Name    Prefix  Num    Val
Tapan   d       1       2
Tapan   d       2       0
Tapan   d       3       3
Tapan   d       4       8
Tapan   d       5       0
Tapan   c       1       12
Tapan   c       2       14
Tapan   c       3       0
Tapan   c       4       0
Tapan   c       5       17
Tapan   c       6       0
```

Then the query is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(prefix, num) AS name, val AS Tapan
FROM yourTable 
WHERE name = 'Tapan' AND val > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b 
ON (a.name = b.name AND (a.d1>0 AND a.d2>0 AND a.d3>0 AND a.d4>0 AND a.d5>0) AND (b.c1>0 AND b.c2>0 AND b.c3>0 AND b.c4>0 AND b.c5>0))
```

Jusr try this, it will work, but it can be made better as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: The above query is not working. Plz check the fiddle   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418248/37